# Float.equals or other best method for comparing whether two floats are equal

Tags: android

I get confused about how to compare two floats whether they are equal or not,in my app the if condition works but in output when i divide a number to zero NaN message pops up and shows, what is wrong, how can I fix it ,as

```
                 case 4:
                     n1=Float.parseFloat(c);
                     n2=Float.parseFloat(a);
                     result=n1/n2;
                     float n3=0f;
                    // if(Float.floatToIntBits(n2)==Float.floatToIntBits(0))
                       if (n2==0)
                     {
                         Toast zermessege=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"عدد تقسیم بر صفر !!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                         zermessege.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT,120,0);
                         zermessege.show();
                         tx.setText("0");


                     }
                      else{
                     tx.setText(result+"");
                     break;}
```

Comment: you cant divide by zero it will give infinity in programming divide by zero exception,

and for comparing float you can use equals

Comment: Some more code please. Your problem is not clear wt is expectations.

Comment: what i want is when the user tries to divide a number to zero a Toast messege shows in case,so i use if condition and said if n2 is ==0, shows the Toast otherwise do somethingele. the app works fne bu when i divide a number by zero it alose shows messeage but in Edittext  a NaN is writtwn

Comment: i want to the Nan not to be there and be erased

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is a bit off. You can never divide any number by 0. The result being "NaN" or "Not a Number".

There are a few logical problems here
1) n1=Float.parseFloat(c); Why are you trying to convert a String value to float. If you can avoid it, try to avoid it. Although Java allows this conversion, we usually would not want to play with the data model's integrity a number should be represented with numbers through the system, unless you cannot avoid it.

2) To compare 2 floats all you need to do it

```
float a = 1f;
float b = 2f;
if(a == b){
// if a and b are equal do this.
}else{
// if a and b are not equal do this.
}
```

3) Now resolving the issue with your code. You cannot divide before your if(n2==0) condition is not met.

```
case 4: 
    n1=Float.parseFloat(c);
                     n2=Float.parseFloat(a);
                     float n3=0f;
                     if (n2==0) {
// do whatever you were doing
                 tx.setText("0");  
                 } else{ 
                 result=n1/n2; 
                 tx.setText(result+""); 
                 break;}
```

Comment: the above code you wrote float a = 1f;
float b = 2f;   yes it is true but  i can not add f to n1 float what should i do

Comment: i also put else{ 
                 result=n1/n2; 
                 tx.setText(result+""); 
                 break;}

Comment: in proper way you recommend

Comment: but still i do know the right way to not display NaN messeage in Edittextbox

Comment: The bottom line is you should never divide by zero.